# I'm trying to make sync code run asynchronously

Tags: python, asynchronous

I have sync code that uses libraries that I cannot change to async. I have async functions that call my sync functions that use sync libraries. How can I make it run async? Do I have to create a wrapper to wrap the sync code?

below is my code:

```
from utils import detect_language


l = ["hello", "hi", "how are you?", "what language am I?"]

async def async_wrapper(i):
    result = detect_language(i)
    return result

async def your_function(i):
    print("Running the function...")
    resp = await async_wrapper(i)
    print(resp)

    
async def run_function_multiple_times(li):
    # Create a list of tasks to store the asynchronous calls
    tasks = []

    for i in li:
        task = asyncio.create_task(your_function(i))
        tasks.append(task)

    await asyncio.gather(*tasks)

asyncio.run(run_function_multiple_times(l))
```

detect_language() function uses the LanguageDetectorBuilder from lingua:

```
from lingua import LanguageDetectorBuilder # Second library to find the language of a text field


async def async_wrapper():
    result = LanguageDetectorBuilder.from_all_languages().with_preloaded_language_models().build()
    return result

async def detect_language(language_html):
    detector = await async_wrapper()

    lang_detect = detect(language_html)
    lingua_detect = detector.detect_language_of(l
```

I wrapped the LanguageDetectorBuilder in a async wrapper, but still it doesn't work. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: There is [asyncio.to_thread](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.to_thread)